# Dropdown click disables hover and trigger JS function on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The dropdown is being triggered on a hover, which is exactly what I want.
The reason for the JS code is to have the dropdown display *over* a parent div.  This works as expected (when clicked, not hovering).

I have the following issues though:

1. The JS function (which works when the dropdown is clicked) is not triggered on a hover, which is what I need to ensure the dropdown is displayed *over* the parent div.
2. If I DO click on the dropdown, the hover effect is disabled.  This is not desirable.  [UPDATE:  this is now resolved by removing the `dropdown-toggle` class `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute.]

I'd appreciate any pointers on the first issue.

```js
(function() {                                       
  var dropdownMenu;

  $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
    $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());

    var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();
    
    dropdownMenu.css({
      'display': 'block',
      'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
      'left': eOffset.left
    });
  });

  $(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());
    dropdownMenu.hide();
  });
})();
```

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <!-- <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> -->

  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/henzen/trLx61a5/109/).